Unknown use 20 V injection in KNX Digital input (read switch status) gvs 4fold

This is a circuit that I've recreated from gvs 4fold digital input.
There is common and wire that goes to 4 switches (this circuit only shows 1 of them) when it it's closed the microcontroller reads it.
But I think in this case it will works without 20 V and the r2 resistor.
I wonder what's it used for. is injecting 20 V like this something to do with wire length or interference?
In my little knowledge about electronics i think the injection of 20 V created a different circuit loop in the same wire so it doesn't affect other circuit.
Please help me to understand what's happening in this circuit.

This circuit doesn't show one switch, it shows /no/ switches.

I suggest learning to use a simulator, there are many but LTspice is a free one that will show you how this circuit works, with and without the 20V and R2.
